# Find $f\left(A\right)$ for a polynomial function of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

So here is the complete question:

Use the given definition to find $f\left(A\right)$: if $f$ is the polynomial function $f\left(x\right)= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ then for a square matrix $A,f\left(A\right)$ is defined to be $f\left(A\right)=a_0I+a_1A+a_2A^2+...+a_nA^n$

$$f\left(x\right)=x^2-5x+2$$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 4 & 5
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So I wasn't sure what to do but I assumed I plugged in $A$ according to the definition supplied.  Can you please provide me with tips to get started?

Edited to include the correct matrix supplied by the question.

Edit again:

$$2\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
 \\ \end{bmatrix}-5\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 4 & 5
 \\ \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0\\ 28 & 25
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this the correct setup?

Comment: It looks like you did exactly the right thing

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, hi, I didn't actually do anything yet, I just guessed.  But is my guess on what to do correct?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation looks right, but that can only finally decided if you give the result of your computation.

Comment: @LutzL I modified the question to include my setup, is this correct?

Comment: @inquisitor: The 16 seems to be wrong. 4*2+5*4 has a different value. Everything else is OK.

Comment: @LutzL I squared the elements in the matrix to get those values.

Comment: @inquisitor Then you're wrong. Matrix multiplication is not done element-wise.

Comment: @tohecz I modified it, does it look better?

Comment: @inquisitor Now it looks correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(\lambda-2)(\lambda-5)=\lambda^{2}-7\lambda+10$. So $A^{2}=7A-10 I$, which can be used to reduce any polynomial expression in $A$ to a linear polynomial expression. For example, in this case,
$$
    A^{2}-5A+2I=2A-8I = 2\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 0 \\ 4 & 5\end{matrix}\right]-8 \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right].
$$
This isn't much easier in your case, but it's a good technique for higher-order expressions.

Comment: Needed to add, the theorem you use is called Hamilton-Cayley Theorem, and is quite non-trivial ;)

Comment: Thank you, @tohecz . That's the correct name.

Comment: I must admit, I don't really understand your answer nor the way you got those values.  Sorry :-(

Comment: If you don't know about the determinant, or about the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=det(\lambda I-A)$ of a matrix $A$, then the answer won't make sense. If you do, then the Hamilton-Cayley Theorem states that $p(A)=0$, which is what I was using. I don't know you background to be able to say.

Comment: The determinant is discussed in our next chapter.

Comment: @inquisitor Ok, then once you know what is _determinant_, you will learn what is the _characteristic polynomial_, and then you can understand (but probably not proof `;)`) the Hamilton-Cayley Theorem. Before you have that, you can verify by hand that your matrix $A$ satisfies the relation $A^2=7A-10I$.